# Pass arg through new shell within script

Tags: powershell, powershell-3.0

I'm trying to call a new shell due to a memory leak from a library. When I call the shell, I need to pass an arg (the real code will pass 2 args). After the block of code has executed in the new shell, it needs to return a value. I wrote some test code to reproduce the error:

```
Function GetLastName
{
    Param ($firstName)

    $lastName = Powershell -firstName $firstName {
        Param ([string]$firstName)
        $lastName = ''
        if ($firstName = 'John')
        {
            $lastName = 'Doe'
            Write-Host "Hello $firstName, your last name is registered as $lastName"
        }
        Write-Host "Last name not found"
        Write-Output $lastName
    }
    Write-Output $lastName
}

Function Main
{
    $firstName = 'John'

    $lastName = GetLastName $firstName

    Write-Host "Your name is $firstName $lastName"
}

Main
```

The error I get...

```
Powershell : -firstName : The term '-firstName' is not recognized as the name of
a cmdlet, function, script file, or operable
At C:\Scripts\Tests\test1.ps1:5 char:15
+         $lastName = Powershell -firstName $firstName {
+                     ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (-firstName : Th...e, or operable :String) [], RemoteException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : NativeCommandError

program. Check the spelling of the name, or if a path was included, verify that
the path is correct and try again.
At line:1 char:1
+ -firstName John -encodedCommand DQAKAAkACQAJAFAAYQByAGEAbQAgACgAWwBzAHQAcgBpAG4A ...
+ ~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : ObjectNotFound: (-firstName:String) [], CommandNotFoundException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : CommandNotFoundException
```

Can anyone help me how to do this?

Comment: Use [`Start-Job` approach](http://stackoverflow.com/a/34300119). It also provide proper separation for Host stream.

Comment: Seems pretty complicated. Can you give an example in the answer section?

Comment: Please stop putting the language tag in the subject of your questions.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The syntax for calling `powershell.exe` to execute a scriptblock from within PowerShell is a bit different:

```
powershell.exe -command { scriptblock content here } -args "arguments","go","here"
```

So in your script that should be:

```
$lastName = powershell -Command {
    Param ([string]$firstName)
    $lastName = ''
    if ($firstName = 'John')
    {
        $lastName = 'Doe'
        Write-Host "Hello $firstName, your last name is registered as $lastName"
    } else {
        Write-Host "Last name not found"
    }
    Write-Output $lastName
} -args $firstName
```

Comment: oh let me test this. Thanks for the reply.

Answer (score 1):

Split your code into two separate scripts and use one just as a launcher for the second. Something like this:

```
# launcher.ps1
powershell.exe -File 'C:\path\to\worker.ps1' -FirstName $firstName
```

---

```
# worker.ps1
[CmdletBinding()]
Param($firstName)

$lastName = ''
if ($firstName = 'John') {
    $lastName = 'Doe'
    Write-Host "Hello $firstName, your last name is registered as $lastName"
}
Write-Host "Last name not found"
Write-Output $lastName
```

Note, however, that from the caller perspective the host output (`Write-Host`) of the new process is merged into its regular output (`Write-Output`).

Comment: well, I was hoping to keep the code in one file, but it looks like this is the best option. The Start-Job is adding unwanted attributes in the table I create.